# AlphaBlend in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, alphablending, delphi-xe5

How can I change `AlphaBlend` value (of a form) in a FireMonkey Desktop Application? Well It's available in VCL Application but I couldn't find it in FireMonkey.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: check `Transparency` (may be useTransparancy) and use `Fill.Color`  with alpha channel value

Comment: Are you trying to change the transparency of a form? Can you provide an image of the desired effect?

Comment: You are looking for a cross-platform solution? or only for Windows?

Comment: @RRUZ No. I think it's impossible too. Only Windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make your form background semitransparent you should set form `Transparency` property  to `true` and use `Fill.Color` with alpha value like `$AAFFFFFF`(with `Fill.Kind = bkSolid`).
in this case form border becomes invisible (at least in Delphi **XE2**)

if you need to make all components at form semitransparent then place `TLayout` on form with `Align = alContents` and set its `Opacity` property to required value.

[image]

if you need semitransparent window with alpha blend as it was in VCL you can use the same methods (for Windows platform) as `getWindowLong/SetWindowLong`. Set `transparency` back to `false` and use code like this in form `OnCreate` event handler:

```
implementation
uses fmx.platform.win, winapi.windows;
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var h : HWND;
    aStyle : integer;
    alphaValue : byte;
begin
    h := WindowHandleToPlatform(self.Handle).Wnd;
    AStyle := GetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLong(h, GWL_EXSTYLE, AStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED);


    AlphaValue := 125;
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(h, 0, alphaValue, LWA_ALPHA);
end;
```

of course all your components become trasparent too.

Comment: Thanks. But the biggest problem is the form borders. They become invisible! How can I fix this?

Comment: ok, @RRUZ has already posted the code from VCL, i'm a litle bit late :)

Comment: Not working for me... I have my form's Fill.Bitmap assigned (splash screen) using XE8. `Transparency` is `True` and `Fill.Color` is `#AAFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are looking only for a Windows implementation you must add the [`WS_EX_LAYERED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) style to your form and then using the  [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method set the alpha value based in a value or a color.

Check this implementation, using a interposer class.

```
type
  TForm   = class(FMX.Forms.TForm)
  private
    FAlphaBlend: Boolean;
    FAlphaBlendValue: Byte;
    FTransparentColor: Boolean;
    FTransparentColorValue: TColor;
    procedure SetAlphaBlend(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetAlphaBlendValue(const Value: Byte);
    procedure SetLayeredAttribs;
    procedure SetTransparentColor(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetTransparentColorValue(const Value: TColor);
  protected
    property AlphaBlend: Boolean read FAlphaBlend write SetAlphaBlend  default False;
    property AlphaBlendValue: Byte read FAlphaBlendValue write SetAlphaBlendValue default 255;
    property TransparentColor: Boolean read FTransparentColor write SetTransparentColor default False;
    property TransparentColorValue: TColor read FTransparentColorValue write SetTransparentColorValue;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
 FMX.Platform.Win,
 Winapi.Windows,
 Vcl.Graphics;

type
  TSetLayeredWindowAttributes = function (Hwnd: THandle; crKey: COLORREF;
    bAlpha: Byte; dwFlags: DWORD): Boolean; stdcall;

var
  SetLayeredWindowAttributes: TSetLayeredWindowAttributes = nil;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   @SetLayeredWindowAttributes := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(User32), 'SetLayeredWindowAttributes');
   AlphaBlend:=True;
   AlphaBlendValue:=200;
end;

{ TForm }

procedure TForm.SetAlphaBlend(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FAlphaBlend <> Value then
  begin
    FAlphaBlend := Value;
    SetLayeredAttribs;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm.SetAlphaBlendValue(const Value: Byte);
begin
  if FAlphaBlendValue <> Value then
  begin
    FAlphaBlendValue := Value;
    SetLayeredAttribs;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm.SetTransparentColor(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FTransparentColor <> Value then
  begin
    FTransparentColor := Value;
    SetLayeredAttribs;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm.SetTransparentColorValue(const Value: TColor);
begin
  if FTransparentColorValue <> Value then
  begin
    FTransparentColorValue := Value;
    SetLayeredAttribs;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm.SetLayeredAttribs;
const
  cUseAlpha: array [Boolean] of Integer = (0, LWA_ALPHA);
  cUseColorKey: array [Boolean] of Integer = (0, LWA_COLORKEY);
var
  AStyle: Integer;
begin
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) and
    (Assigned(SetLayeredWindowAttributes))  then
  begin

    AStyle := GetWindowLong( WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    if FAlphaBlend or FTransparentColor then
    begin
      if (AStyle and WS_EX_LAYERED) = 0 then
        SetWindowLong(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, AStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED);
      SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, ColorToRGB(FTransparentColorValue), FAlphaBlendValue,
        cUseAlpha[FAlphaBlend] or cUseColorKey[FTransparentColor]);
    end
    else
    begin
      SetWindowLong(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, AStyle and not WS_EX_LAYERED);
      RedrawWindow(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, nil, 0, RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_FRAME or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the ColorKey yourself ? While using LWA_ALPHA works fine for me I can't get the other part to work, passing the ColorKey (and defining LWA_COLORKEY) seems to have no effect.