# Transparent Form in firemonkey with a stylebook

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, alpha-transparency, firemonkey-style

I have a application with multiple stylebooks containing styles from delphistyles.com. I want to add a trackbar to allow the user to change the transparency of the form at runtime like you can do in VCL with alphablend.

This post: [AlphaBlend in FireMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699032/alphablend-in-firemonkey) says the following:

> To make your form background semitransparent you should set form Transparency property to true and use Fill.Color with alpha value like $AAFFFFFF(with Fill.Kind = bkSolid). in this case form border becomes invisible (at least in Delphi XE2)

But how can I achieve this when my form has a stylebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set TForm.Transparency to True
2. Put TPanel on the form with Align = Content
3. Use your TPanel as conteiner for all controls
4. Use TPanel.Opacity for transparency

Comment: The opacity does nothing. It's barley visible no matter if you change the opacity.

Comment: Ahh I see my one style I was trying it on had a transparent panel as a style. Another thing is when the main form is transparent how can I go about making a titlebar for the user to drag the form?

Answer (score -1):

> Another thing is when the main form is transparent how can I go about making a titlebar for the user to drag the form?

I use my own class *TWindowMove* for moving forms without titlebar. [Thats](https://c2n.me/3UDwKLV.zip) a small demo project