# Creating transparent Forms (or Activities?) in Firemonkey Delphi for Android

Tags: android, delphi

I want to create a transparent activity (or should I call it Form?) in Delphi (FMX) for Android, like this user does in his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIfCGDRQ9EI).

Is it possible to do it with Delphi?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AlphaBlend in FireMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699032/alphablend-in-firemonkey)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551160/transparent-form-in-firemonkey-with-a-stylebook

Comment: The latter solved my problem!